# Adapt parent to maximum size of it's children in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make parent div adjust it's height to max of it's children height and width to max width of it's children width?

```css
* { box-sizing: content-box; }

.parent {
  position: relative;
  
  border: 2px solid blue;
  
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
}

.child-a {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  
  width: 135px;
  height: 100px;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.child-b {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 135px;
  
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-a' />
  <div class='child-b' />
</div>
```

I tried various combinations of position, top, left attributes in the example above.

[image: wanted parent layout]

Maybe it is possible to achieve this effect at least in one dimension?

Comment: If you want to keep the absolute positioning, then you have to set the height to be the same as the height of your child-b. So `.parent { height: 135px }` This is not the best way.

Comment: Not with position absolute - Is that a requirement?

Comment: @ArmedinKuka thank you for the response. The point is that parent does not know the children sizes in advance and should adapt it's size to the minimum size that does not overflow.

Comment: @Paulie_D no, there are no position specific requirements.

Comment: Using absolute positioning, it's very unlikely to do it. That is because absolutely positioned elements are completely removed from the document flow, and thus their dimensions cannot alter the dimensions of their parents. Instead you can use grids to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible *without* `position:absolute` using CSS-Grid and layering the elements in the same grid cell.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
  display: grid;
}

.child-a {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 135px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.child-b {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100px;
  height: 135px;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-a'></div>
  <div class='child-b'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple float can do this if you want better support than CSS grid

```css
* { box-sizing: content-box; }

.parent {
  display:inline-block; /* This */
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.child-a {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  float:left; /* and this */
  width: 135px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child-b {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100px;
  height: 135px;
}

/* To illustrate that it works whataver the width/height */
.parent:hover .child-b{
  width:180px;
}
.parent:hover .child-a{
  height:180px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-a' ></div>
  <div class='child-b' ></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can achieve this via CSS grid.

```css
* { box-sizing: content-box; }

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "grid-overlap";
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: auto;
  width: max-content;
}

.child-a {
  grid-area: grid-overlap;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 135px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: overlay; 

}

.child-b {
  grid-area: grid-overlap;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100px;
  height: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-a'></div>
  <div class='child-b'></div>
</div>
```